# ngModel using Map for select

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I would like to use a Map to hold the selected value for each row in my data table.  I would like to avoid adding a special field to the record object.  Here is a Plunker of what I am trying to do http://plnkr.co/edit/OKqZ80?p=info and a listing of the example component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    // public power: string,  // I do not have a power field in the actual class I am using 
    public alterEgo?: string
  ) {  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<h1>Select with Map</h1>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Hero</th>
      <th>Power</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes">

      <td>{{hero.name}}</td>

      <td>

        <select [(ngModel)]="selectedPowers[hero.name]">
          <option *ngFor="let power of powers" [ngValue]="power">{{power}}</option>
        </select>

      </td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<pre>{{ selectedPowers | json }}</pre>
`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = new Array<Hero>();
  powers = ['Really Smart', 'Super Flexible',
            'Super Hot', 'Weather Changer'];
  selectedPowers: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(11, 'Mr. Nice'));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(12, 'Narco'));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(13, 'Bombasto'));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(14, 'Celeritas'));

    this.selectedPowers.set(this.heroes[0].name, this.powers[0]);
  }
}
```

I am trying to accomplish two things:  first, I want the dropdown to show the selected power for each hero; and second, I want the `selectedPowers` field to reflect the changes made in the table.

There seems to be some problem with the Plunker version: when I run as a local node project, the PRE tag shows the changes I make to the dropdowns.

EDIT 1: I do not have a power field in my actual class.  Changed the Plunker too.

Answer (score 1):

you may try below,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public name: string,
    public power: string,
    public alterEgo?: string
  ) {  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<h1>Select with Map</h1>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Hero</th>
      <th>Power</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
      <td>
        <select (change)="changePower(hero.name, $event.currentTarget.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let power of powers" [value]="power" [selected]="power === hero.power" >{{power}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<pre>{{ selectedPowers | json }}</pre>
`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = new Array<Hero>();
  powers = ['Really Smart', 'Super Flexible',
            'Super Hot', 'Weather Changer'];
  selectedPowers: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();

  changePower(heroName,power){
   this.selectedPowers.set(heroName, power);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(11, 'Mr. Nice',  this.powers[0]));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(12, 'Narco',     this.powers[1]));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(13, 'Bombasto',  this.powers[2]));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(14, 'Celeritas', this.powers[3]));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(15, 'Magneta',   this.powers[0]));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(16, 'RubberMan', this.powers[1]));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(17, 'Dynama',    this.powers[2]));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(18, 'Dr IQ',     this.powers[3]));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(19, 'Magma',     this.powers[0]));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(20, 'Tornado',   this.powers[1]));

   //  this.selectedPowers.set(this.heroes[0].name, this.powers[0]);
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](http://plnkr.co/edit/jVUYiq?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: That is pretty good, but you are still using `hero.power` in the view.  In my actual situation, I am using someone else's hero object which does not have a power field, so I can only access the Map.